# Algorithm for finding optimal zone coverage

Tags: algorithm

I have a few points randomly distributed over a 2D-map. I also have a finite number of circles that I want to place so they cover as many of the points as possible, kind of like a turret-game AI that places turrets in a base to protect valuable buildings. Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like a form of the [maximum coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem). One simple way to solve this problem is applying the [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm).

This means you start by drawing the first circle such that it covers the biggest possible region. Then you draw the second circle such that it covers the biggest possible area and so on.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!